# Trying to add a django app to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

So, I've synced a Django app from GitHub to Heroku, and I was trying to deploy from their web interface, but in the log it says

```
Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

See traceback above for details.
You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
   $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
Push failed
```

I understand that you can use Heroku CLI to disable collectstatic, but I couldn't find a way to sync my GitHub/Heroku app with Heroku CLI.

Answer (score 0):

So,it seems the culprit was something else in my case,i didn't add a proper variable to ALLOWED_HOSTS,adding the heroku app fixed it